# Create an actor with a BoundedMessageQueue

Tags: akka.net

we need to create an Actor that discards messages once it's mailbox is filled up to a certain size.
Browsing the assemblies reveiled that there is a `BoundedMessageQueue` already implemented offering the options:

1. mailbox-capacity
2. mailbox-push-timeout-time

We could not figure out the correct syntax how to create an actor with a `BoundedMessageQueue` and the appropriate settings. The closest we could get was `Props.Create(...).WithMailbox(???)`

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BoundedMailbox`](http://getakka.net/api/Akka.Dispatch.BoundedMailbox.html), which is backed by `BoundedMessageQueue`.

In your configuration (note that the mailbox needs to be defined outside of the `akka` namespace):

```cs
akka { ... }

bounded-mailbox {
    mailbox-capacity = 1000
    mailbox-push-timeout-time = 10s
    mailbox-type = "Akka.Dispatch.BoundedMailbox, Akka"
}
```

Then, to create an actor with this mailbox:

```cs
Props.Create<ActorType>().WithMailbox("bounded-mailbox");
```